# passing id to a modal in laravel

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

So in a list of users, there's a suspend button, if the suspend button is click, a modal pops up for the admin to type in the reason for suspend. and when send button is pressed that specific user should get a mail with the reason the admin typed.

Now my problem is that no matter the user's suspend button i click, its only the first user in the database the email is sent to.(even if i click on the 7th, or 12th or any other user in my table, the email is sent to the 1st user in the database)

below is my code, please help

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <div class="actions">
                    <a href="{{ route('update_status', $user->user_id) }}" id="suspendd" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#demoModal"
                        class="btn btn-sm bg-danger-light">Suspend</a>
                </div>
            </td>
             <!-- Modal Example Start-->
             <div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" value="{{$user->user_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="demoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="demoModalLabel">
                                Reason to Suspend This User</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close"
                                data-dismiss="modal" aria- label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <textarea rows="5" cols="15" class="form-control summernote" placeholder="Compose mail here" name="details"
                                value="details" id="details" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <a href="{{ route('update_status', $user->user_id) }}"
                                class="btn btn-primary"><i
                                    class="fa fa-send m-r-5"></i><span>Send</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Modal Example End-->
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you referenced to only one modal which is the first. From your code, every single modal will have the same `id` value.
So instead what you should do is attach a number or something unique to each of the modals. You could go like this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <div class="actions">
                    <a href="{{ route('update_status', $user->user_id) }}" id="suspendd" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#demoModal{{ $user->user_id }}"
                        class="btn btn-sm bg-danger-light">Suspend</a>
                </div>
            </td>
             <!-- Modal Example Start-->
             <div class="modal fade" id="demoModal{{ $user->user_id }}" value="{{$user->user_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="demoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="demoModalLabel{{ $user->user_id }}">
                                Reason to Suspend This User</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close"
                                data-dismiss="modal" aria- label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <textarea rows="5" cols="15" class="form-control summernote" placeholder="Compose mail here" name="details"
                                value="details" id="details" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <a href="{{ route('update_status', $user->user_id) }}"
                                class="btn btn-primary"><i
                                    class="fa fa-send m-r-5"></i><span>Send</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Modal Example End-->
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

So now each modal would have a unique `id` rather than what you did before where all button clicks led to the same first modal being popped up.

Comment: I don't know how to do but it will be good to pass a user id on button click to a form inside a single modal instead of creating a separate modal for every user in foreach loop.

Comment: @Jabroo That is correct. But I tailored the solution to the OPs implementation attempt.